# Can an upvoted question with accepted upvoted answer be deleted?

Tags: discussion, upvotes, vote-to-delete

Take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12737515/how-do-you-pronounce-tuple) ([screenshot for <10k users](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CwfzS.png)), this is blatantly off-topic (though we no longer close questions with a reason like this). IMO it should be deleted, it has nothing to do with programming, except it mentions a term that is used in some programming languages.

How do we handle questions like this?

**Update** The question is almost an identical duplicate of [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/691437/how-do-you-pronounce-the-word-tuple), that got deleted. Why should we treat this question differently?

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5221/how-does-deleting-work-what-can-cause-a-post-to-be-deleted-and-what-does-that

Comment: Yes, it can be deleted. does it need to be? it's closed fortunately.

Comment: *"The question is almost an identical duplicate of this one, that got deleted. Why should we treat this questing differently"* - or why should the other question not be undeleted? The question was so nice and focussed without the update, this just muddies the water.

Comment: @Gimby I've said this before, I'm not questioning the question quality, the question is well-formed, and with a clear goal. Why I'm saying is that the question doesn't belong to SO, a site oriented towards programming questions. And it was asked also on a [more appropriate site](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/12980/how-to-pronounce-tuple).

Comment: I just voted to delete. I think it requires 7 votes, then it's gone. 20k+ use your powers. for me, the fact that 1 user (who's off topic) accepted the answer doesn't mean a thing on the quality of the answer. We're talking ancien times. SO is way more serious now, and it's for the best

Comment: The question has now been deleted

Comment: Maybe it could be a case for a [historical lock](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/126587/274671).

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro I doubt such a question qualifies for an historical lock.

Comment: @Cristik Yes, probably not. Even if popular and with high views, it was already off-topic when it was written.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Yes, questions can be deleted even if they are upvoted, and even if they have upvoted, accepted answers. An upvoted answer or accepted answer prevents a question *asker* from deleting their own question, but anyone else with delete vote privileges can cast a delete vote on a closed question, provided it has been closed long enough.

As for how we handle pronunciation questions? Close them as off-topic. Stack Overflow is not the place for pronunciation questions, even if they are helpful to some people. Even if they are about how to pronounce programming words. They are still English pronunciation questions and not programming questions. In the same vein, I could ask a finance-related question about software here and it could be viewed by thousands and upvoted by many, but that doesn't mean it belongs here. Such a question should also be closed as off-topic.

Normally, in the case of a good pronunciation question (which are rare) being asked, we would probably migrate it to the English Language & Usage site. In this case, the question is too old for migration, so outright deletion is appropriate.

Answer (score -2):

A terminology question which has been seen 10,000 times over the course of 6 years, which isn't the *worst* question and answer pair that I've seen on the site.  Should it be deleted?  I  don't think so; it's not actively *harmful*.  It may even be *helping* someone out there.  Closed? Sure.  Keep it that way.  It doesn't need more answers.

Comment: I'm debating the quality of the question, but the fact that it has no place on SO. Plus, it's an almost identical duplicate of an already deleted question.

Comment: I somehow [doubt that it may be helping](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QTTQR.png)

Comment: @gnat: I can't convince Google search to give me that page, and Google dictionary doesn't even seem to know that "tuple" is a word. So I'm just guessing what your screenshot might have said if you hit the play button, but I don't think I've ever heard "tuple" pronounced in a way which might be represented as "tjuple". Is that the nyoocler option, do you think? (Although when I look up possibly palatalized words like tulip, Google presents the phonetics as "t(y)oo...", not "tju...".)

Comment: @rici Such search results can be affected by your region and your search settings.

Comment: @tyler: i'm aware of that but i wonder if the indicated pronunciation is part of the customization. That might be considered by some to be going too far :-) (Although it makes no attempt to adjust the phonetics of "nuclear" to conform to my sensibilities.)

Comment: @rici I meant the pronunciation guide showing up at all.

Comment: @TylerH If the Google dictionary / pronunciation guide doesn't show up, you can try to force it to by adding `define` before your search query, i.e. search for `define tuple`